# samsung galaxy phone jack pinout to pc

Tags: android, audio-recording

I'm trying to get the audio-out from a Samsung Galaxy A4 into a PC for recording with Audacity. I've tried a 3.5mm 4-pin (TRRS) and 3-pin (TRS) cable into the MIC input jack on the PC but none of them produce any audio out.

If I plug in official Samsung in-ear headphones (with has a 3.5mm 3-pin plug) the audio on the app is silenced and it goes through the headphones (as expected), but if I plug in a 3-pin to 3-pin straight-through cable and connect it to the PC MIC input jack the app on the phone simply ignores it and outputs the audio from the phone.

What's the magic behind this and how can I make a cable that will allow me to record audio from my phone on my PC?

Comment: You may have more luck on the [EE Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll re-post there..